# Marcumq Function In MATLAB

Tags: matlab, distribution, mean

I am working with log-normal distribution and now i have problem with marcumq function in MATLAB. Here is my code:

```
N = 10^5;        %//sample
x1 = randn(N,1); %//creat random variable x1
mean = 1;        %//mean of x1
sigma = 0.4;     %//variance of x1

x = mean + sqrt(sigma).*x1; %//random variable x
y = exp(x);                 %//log-normal random variable
z = 0:0.1:150;
[n,xout] = hist(y,z); %//frequency counts and the bin locations

m = 5; 
Base = 0.01:0.02:1;
Pf = Base.^2;       
lamda = gaminv(1-Pf,m)*2; %//value of decision threshold

  for i = 1:1:1501
    Q = marcumq(sqrt(2*m*xout(i)),sqrt(lamda),m);
  end
```

My problem is: i cannot determine value of Q in "Q = marcumq(sqrt(2*m*xout(i)),sqrt(lamda),m);". It return value of Q is 1 in all of elements when i run my program. I need your help to help me fix this error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OK so I misunderstood the function initially.

The value you get for Q after running your script is only based on the last value in xout so that is probably not what you want.

Can you describe what you are trying to do?

You value for lambda is not a scalar, but a vector. Is that what you want? That means that for each time you call marcumq, you get a vector of values out.

Q = 1 seems to happen when your first input is bigger than your second input - these are your integral limits, so if the lower limit is bigger than the upper, no integration will happen.

From a brief test of your code, your xout values are higher than your lambda values. Also are you sure you want to be using xout? These are just the bin values, which are equal to z.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i tried by your tip but it still not working.It notice:"Dimensions of arguments do not match." :-(

Comment: thanks for your support. i will try again. thank you so much, my friend :-)

Comment: yep. The first things: to describe what are you trying to do. it is quite difficult for me to express. It's a complicated problem and I tried to express my problem is simply as possible :(
- The second things: i determine value of lamda is a vector, yes, that's right. And i want to archive value of Q is a vector which i will use to plot diagram.
- The third: yes, i totaly agree with you and i want to say thanks for your tip. it look like better.
- The last thing: i am sure that, i want to use value of xout.

Comment: i have changed possition of sqrt(2*m*xout(i))and sqrt(lamda). it look like better :-s

Comment: Why are you using the histogram function at all, then, instead of just using `z`? You aren't using `n`, the counts, anywhere that I can see. Glad that swapping your arguments seems to help.

Comment: we can discuss my problem with each other via yahoo, facebook or skype. Thanks for your help.
My yahoo: super_crazy_1991
my skyper:super_crazy_1991
my facebook:humandance1991@gmail.com